# Custom Input format for input split in hadoop

Tags: java, hadoop, mapreduce, input-split

Am I able to get entire `input split` into mapper rather than each line of inputsplit into mapper.

For this I need to implement my own Custom Input format.
but if I am writing `WholeFileInputFormat`

**Whether it means the mapper get the entire line or entire input split?**

Does **NLineInputFormat** solves my problem?

Answer (score 0):

I wouldn't bother with `NLineInputFormat`.  You probably don't always know what *N* is and you don't need the overhead of the input format reading each file to find the line byte offsets.

The `WholeFileInputFormat` from [here](https://github.com/tomwhite/hadoop-book/tree/master/ch07/src/main/java) (which I assume what you're referencing) will pass the entire file as the value to the `map` method.

Comment: But whether that is the full input file or input split.If it is full input file - How can Hadoop manage the  file while using WholeInputFormat as map gets the whole file content and no parallizing will be done also..